# object to Tuple with list and dictionary c#

Tags: c#-4.0, tuples

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 10,
      "title": "Administration",
      "active": true,
      "type": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Manager"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 207,
      "title": "MCO - Exact Match 1",
      "active": true,
      "type": {
        "id": 128,
        "name": "Group"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 1201,
      "title": "Regression",
      "active": false,
      "type": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Manager"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

i am trying to create a tuple in the below format using linq. not sure how to start with group/aggregate. Any help is appreciated. I went over few threads and could not able to find something similar to this.

```
var tuple = new List<Tuple<int, List<Dictionary<int,bool>>>();
                              2                10, true    
                                               1201, false
                              128              207,  true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a full working code:

```cs
        var o = new {
            data = new [] {
                new {
                    id = 10,
                    title = "Administration",
                    active = true,
                    type = new {
                        id = 2,
                        name = "Manager"
                    }
                },
                new {
                    id = 207,
                    title = "MCO - Exact Match 1",
                    active = true,
                    type = new {
                        id = 128,
                        name = "Group"
                    }
                },
                new {
                    id = 1201,
                    title = "Regression",
                    active = false,
                    type = new {
                        id = 2,
                        name = "Manager"
                    }
                }               
            }
        };

        var result = o.data.GroupBy(
            item => item.type.id, // the group key
            item => new Dictionary<int, bool>() {{ item.id, item.active }}, // the transformed elements in the group
            (id, items) => new Tuple<int, List<Dictionary<int, bool>>>(id, items.ToList()) // transformation of grouping result to the final desired format
        ).ToList();

        // check correctness
        foreach (var entry in result) {
            Console.Write(entry.Item1);
            foreach (var dict in entry.Item2) {
                foreach (var kvp in dict)
                    Console.WriteLine("\t\t" + kvp.Key + "\t" + kvp.Value);
            }
        }
```

And this is how it works:

- `o` is the data model, represented using anonymous types. You can obviously use a strongly typed model here, if you already have it;
- on `o` we apply the four-argument version of GroupBy, described in detail in the [official docs from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netcore-3.1#System_Linq_Enumerable_GroupBy__4_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__System_Func___0___2__System_Func___1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___2____3__). Basically:

  - the first lambda expression selects the group key;
  - the second lambda defines the elements that are part of each group;
  - the third lambda transforms each (group key, enumeration of group elements) into the `Tuple<int, List<Dictionary<int, bool>>>` format;
  - at the end we call ToList() to compute the result and store it as a list of tuples.
- the last part prints the result (did not spend much time prettifying it, but it does its job validating the code).

Comment: Thanks so much for your timely help and also thanks for the explanation. have a nice day